# sum a 3x3 array on a given point to another matrix maintaining boundaries

Tags: python, numpy

suppose I have this 2d array A:

```
[[0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,4]]
```

and I want to sum B:

```
[[1,2,3]
 [4,5,6]
 [7,8,9]]
```

centered on A[0][0] so the result would be:

```
array_sum(A,B,0,0) =
[[5,6,0,4],
 [8,9,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [2,0,0,5]]
```

I was thinking that I should make a function that compares if its on a boundary and then adjust the index for that:

```
def array_sum(A,B,i,f):
   ...
   if i == 0 and j == 0:
      A[-1][-1] = A[-1][-1]+B[0][0]
      ...

   else:
      A[i-1][j-1] = A[i][j]+B[0][0]
      A[i][j] = A[i][j]+B[1][1]
      A[i+1][j+1] = A[i][j]+B[2][2]
      ...
```

but I don't know if there is a better way of doing that, I was reading about broadcasting or maybe using convolute for that, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to do that.

Comment: Adjusting for boundary is not a bad idea, but there are better ways of doing it than having 9 if statements.

Comment: dimensions of `B` will always be odd?

Comment: yes @DanielF it will be always a 3x3 matrix

Comment: Can you explain why the last row of A+B is `2 0 0 5`?

Comment: 2 from [1,2,3] going top (goes to next boundary), 5 from [1,2,3]
 1 + 4 from B[-1,-1] @Shir

Comment: shouldn't it be `2 3 0 5`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `B.shape` is all odd numbers, you can use `np.indices`, manipulate them to point where you want, and use `np.add.at`

```
def array_sum(A, B, loc = (0, 0)):
    A_ = A.copy()
    ix = np.indices(B.shape)
    new_loc = np.array(loc) - np.array(B.shape) // 2
    new_ix = np.mod(ix + new_loc[:, None, None], 
                    np.array(A.shape)[:, None, None])
    np.add.at(A_, tuple(new_ix), B)
    return A_
```

Testing:

```
array_sum(A, B)
Out:
array([[ 5.,  6.,  0.,  4.],
       [ 8.,  9.,  0.,  7.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  0.,  5.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb slice indexing is faster (~2x) than fancy indexing. This appears to be true even for the small example in OP. Downside: the code is slightly more complicated.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import s_ as _
from itertools import product, starmap

def wrapsl1d(N, n, c):
    # check in 1D whether a patch of size n centered at c in a vector
    # of length N fits or has to be wrapped around
    # return appropriate slice objects for both vector and patch
    assert n <= N
    l = (c - n//2) % N
    h = l + n
    # return list of pairs (index into A, index into patch)
    # 2 pairs if we wrap around, otherwise 1 pair
    return [_[l:h, :]] if h <= N else [_[l:, :N-l], _[:h-N, n+N-h:]]

def use_slices(A, patch, center=(0, 0)):
    slAptch = product(*map(wrapsl1d, A.shape, patch.shape, center))
    # the product now has elements [(idx0A, idx0ptch), (idx1A, idx1ptch)]
    # transpose them:
    slAptch = starmap(zip, slAptch)
    out = A.copy()
    for sa, sp in slAptch:
        out[sa] += patch[sp]
    return out
```